# Solstheim How To Survive as a Vampire From Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I finally started Dragonborn DLC. I traveled by boat from Windhelm to Solstheim. When I landed there, the weather was very gloomy but sun-rich.

Blood-cursed arrows fired at the sun do not work at blocking out the sun fired from Auriel's bow. In Skyrim they create a marvelous sun-block where vampires can flourish. But in Solstheim, Auriel's bow refuses to work.

I also tried the Clear Skies shout to see if it works. It does not work.

What can I do except for burn in the sun?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auriel's Bow can blot out the sun in Solthsteim, though it is much harder to do given the dense clouds. At noon, the sun will be directly overhead, which makes targeting it much easier.

That said, the sun is a much lesser threat to vampires in Skyrim than it was in Oblivion, and if your character is fairly powerful you will barely notice its adverse effects. Improving your stamina and magicka regeneration though enchantments, perks and potions will help you offset the stunted daytime regeneration. You can also avoid going into battle outside during the day, I can't recall any part of the DLC that would require you to fight outside during the day.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid frustration when trying to target the sun with Auriel's Bow and Bloodcursed Elven Arrows, just install a mod like that stops sun damage effects to vampires altogether. What I use is the mod, **[Vampire No Sun Damage - Cloaks Helmets and Hoods](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/31221/?)**.